# Ignite Cache Store - Method to release resources

Tags: caching, ignite, gridgain

I have implemented Ignite cache store using HBase as the back-end persistent store. The code for the Cache Store is as follows :

```
public class BitDataCachePersistentStore implements CacheStore<Long, byte[]> {

@IgniteInstanceResource
Ignite gridReference;

@CacheNameResource
private String cacheName;

@Override
public byte[] load(Long key) {

    String hbaseKey;

    try (Connection con = HBaseConnectionUtil.getHbaseConnection()) {

        try (Table bitDataPersistentTable = con.getTable(TagDuplicateConstants.BIT_DATA_TABLE_NAME)) {

            hbaseKey = TagDuplicateUtil.getPersistentStoreKeyForBitDataCache(cacheName, key.toString());

            Get rowToBeFetched = new Get(Bytes.toBytes(hbaseKey));

            Result rowFetched = bitDataPersistentTable.get(rowToBeFetched);

            if (rowFetched == null || rowFetched.isEmpty()) {
                return null; // Can't return an empty array as Ignite will
                                // load the entry
            }

            return rowFetched.getValue(TagDuplicateConstants.BIT_DATA_COLUMN_FAMILY_NAME_AS_BYTES,
                    TagDuplicateConstants.BIT_DATA_COLUMN_QUALIFIER_NAME_AS_BYTES);

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ROCException(TagDuplicateErrorCodes.CACHE_ENTRY_READ_ERROR, e,
                "Error while performing read operation for the key [ " + key + " ] of the cache [ " + cacheName
                        + " ] ");
    }

}

@Override
public Map<Long, byte[]> loadAll(Iterable<? extends Long> keys) {

    String hbaseKey;

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long numberOfKeysLoaded = 0l;

    try (Connection con = HBaseConnectionUtil.getHbaseConnection()) {

        try (Table bitDataPersistentTable = con.getTable(TagDuplicateConstants.BIT_DATA_TABLE_NAME)) {

            IgniteCache<Long, byte[]> cacheToBeLoaded = gridReference.cache(cacheName);

            Get rowToBeFetched;

            Result rowFetched;

            for (Long key : keys) {

                hbaseKey = TagDuplicateUtil.getPersistentStoreKeyForBitDataCache(cacheName, key.toString());

                rowToBeFetched = new Get(Bytes.toBytes(hbaseKey));

                rowFetched = bitDataPersistentTable.get(rowToBeFetched);

                cacheToBeLoaded.put(key,
                        rowFetched.getValue(TagDuplicateConstants.BIT_DATA_COLUMN_FAMILY_NAME_AS_BYTES,
                                TagDuplicateConstants.BIT_DATA_COLUMN_QUALIFIER_NAME_AS_BYTES));

                numberOfKeysLoaded++;

            }

            System.out.println("LoadAll for [ " + numberOfKeysLoaded + " ] keys of the cache [ " + cacheName
                    + " ] took [ " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000.0) + " seconds ] ");

            return null;

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ROCException(TagDuplicateErrorCodes.CACHE_ENTRY_READ_ERROR, e,
                "Error while reading multiple keys for the cache [ " + cacheName + " ] ");
    }

}

@Override
public void write(Entry<? extends Long, ? extends byte[]> entry) {

    String hbaseKey = TagDuplicateUtil.getPersistentStoreKeyForBitDataCache(cacheName, entry.getKey().toString());

    try (Connection con = HBaseConnectionUtil.getHbaseConnection()) {

        try (Table bitDataPersistentTable = con.getTable(TagDuplicateConstants.BIT_DATA_TABLE_NAME)) {

            Put rowToBeWritten = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(hbaseKey));

            rowToBeWritten.addColumn(TagDuplicateConstants.BIT_DATA_COLUMN_FAMILY_NAME_AS_BYTES,
                    TagDuplicateConstants.BIT_DATA_COLUMN_QUALIFIER_NAME_AS_BYTES, entry.getValue());

            bitDataPersistentTable.put(rowToBeWritten);

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ROCException(TagDuplicateErrorCodes.CACHE_ENTRY_WRITE_ERROR, e,
                "Error while writing the entry for the key [ " + entry.getKey() + " ] for the cache [ " + cacheName
                        + " ] ");
    }

}

@Override
public void writeAll(Collection<Entry<? extends Long, ? extends byte[]>> entries) {

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    String hbaseKey;

    List<Put> rowsToBeWritten = new ArrayList<>();

    Put currentRowToBeWritten;

    try (Connection con = HBaseConnectionUtil.getHbaseConnection()) {

        try (Table bitDataPersistentTable = con.getTable(TagDuplicateConstants.BIT_DATA_TABLE_NAME)) {

            for (Entry<? extends Long, ? extends byte[]> entryToBeInserted : entries) {

                hbaseKey = TagDuplicateUtil.getPersistentStoreKeyForBitDataCache(cacheName,
                        entryToBeInserted.getKey().toString());

                currentRowToBeWritten = new Put(hbaseKey.getBytes());

                currentRowToBeWritten.addColumn(TagDuplicateConstants.BIT_DATA_COLUMN_FAMILY_NAME_AS_BYTES,
                        TagDuplicateConstants.BIT_DATA_COLUMN_QUALIFIER_NAME_AS_BYTES,
                        entryToBeInserted.getValue());

                rowsToBeWritten.add(currentRowToBeWritten);

            }

            bitDataPersistentTable.put(rowsToBeWritten);

        }

        System.out.println("Time taken to load [ " + entries.size() + " entries ] for the cache [ " + cacheName
                + " ] is " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000.0) + " seconds");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ROCException(TagDuplicateErrorCodes.CACHE_ENTRY_WRITE_ERROR, e,
                "Error while writing multiple keys for the cache [ " + cacheName + " ] ");
    }

}

@Override
public void delete(Object key) {

    String hbaseKey = TagDuplicateUtil.getPersistentStoreKeyForBitDataCache(cacheName, key.toString());

    try (Connection con = HBaseConnectionUtil.getHbaseConnection()) {

        try (Table bitDataPersistentTable = con.getTable(TagDuplicateConstants.BIT_DATA_TABLE_NAME)) {

            Delete rowToBeDeleted = new Delete(Bytes.toBytes(hbaseKey));

            bitDataPersistentTable.delete(rowToBeDeleted);

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ROCException(TagDuplicateErrorCodes.CACHE_ENTRY_REMOVAL_ERROR, e,
                "Error while deleting the entry for the key [ " + hbaseKey + " ] for the cache [ " + cacheName
                        + " ] ");
    }

}

@Override
public void deleteAll(Collection<?> keys) {

    String hbaseKey;

    List<Delete> rowsToBeDeleted = new ArrayList<>();

    try (Connection con = HBaseConnectionUtil.getHbaseConnection()) {

        try (Table bitDataPersistentTable = con.getTable(TagDuplicateConstants.BIT_DATA_TABLE_NAME)) {

            for (Object keyToBeDeleted : keys) {

                hbaseKey = TagDuplicateUtil.getPersistentStoreKeyForBitDataCache(cacheName,
                        keyToBeDeleted.toString());

                rowsToBeDeleted.add(new Delete(hbaseKey.getBytes()));

            }

            bitDataPersistentTable.delete(rowsToBeDeleted);

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ROCException(TagDuplicateErrorCodes.CACHE_ENTRY_REMOVAL_ERROR, e,
                "Error while deleting entries for the cache [ " + cacheName + " ] ");
    }

}

@Override
public void loadCache(IgniteBiInClosure<Long, byte[]> clo, Object... args) {
    // No implementation provided
}

@Override
public void sessionEnd(boolean commit) {
    // No implementation provided
}

}
```

The cache mode is PARTITIONED.

The cache atomicity mode is ATOMIC.

It is evident from the store implementation that I am spawning a new connection to HBase in each and every one of the implemented methods.

I wanted to know if there is any method or way to have more control over opening and closing my data source specific resources ( In this case, HBase connections ) at a more macro level instead of performing it at every method invocation.

Comment: Perhaps look at pooling the connections

Answer (score 2):

You need to use connection pool in your store. Check out [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/).